# In R, sort a list of dataframes by name, then calculate sum of two columns in each data frame

Tags: r, list, sorting, dataframe, apply

I searched the forum for a bit, but I couldn't find a question that's similar to the one I have. Basically, I have a `list` of `dataframes` that have the same column names. I want to first sort the `dataframes` in the list by number, then calculate the `sum` of `Col1` and `Col2` in each `dataframes` and then store it in a vector that reflects the sorted list of `dataframes`.

I thought list `[order(names(list))]` would work, but it didn't.

For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col1=c(1,2,3,4,5),Col2=c(2,3,4,5,6), Col3=rep(a,5)) 
df3 <- data.frame(Col1=c(5,4,3,2,1),Col2=c(6,5,4,3,2), Col3=rep(a,5))
df2 <- data.frame(Col1=c(1,2,3,4,5),Col2=c(1,2,3,4,5), Col3=rep(a,5))
list <- list(df1, df3, df2)
>list
$df1
Col1 Col2 Col3
   1    2    a
   2    3    a
   3    4    a
   4    5    a
   5    6    a

$df3
Col1 Col2 Col3
   5    6    a
   4    5    a
   3    4    a
   2    3    a
   1    2    a

$df2
Col1 Col2 Col3
   1    1    a
   2    2    a
   3    3    a
   4    4    a
   5    5    a
```

First, I want to sort it, like this

```
$df1
Col1 Col2 Col3
   1    2    a
   2    3    a
   3    4    a
   4    5    a
   5    6    a

$df2
Col1 Col2 Col3
   1    1    a
   2    2    a
   3    3    a
   4    4    a
   5    5    a

$df3
Col1 Col2 Col3
   5    6    a
   4    5    a
   3    4    a
   2    3    a
   1    2    a
```

Then, I want to get the sum of Col1 and Col2 in each dataframe, and store it in a new vector (let's call it `x`). The result should look like this

```
x
35, 30, 35
```

With what I presented, I would imagine that there is both a `for-loop` solution and a `lapply` solution.

Comment: Pretty sure lists of dataframes don't store names...? Are you talking about this sort of:  

d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3),y2=c(4,5,6))   
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1),y2=c(6,5,4))    
my.list <- list(d1, d2)

Comment: Yup! So now, my.list is considered a nonatomic element because it contains dataframes as elements.

Comment: `list <- list(df1=df1, df3=df3, df2=df2); sapply(list[order(names(list))], sum)`

Comment: @Khashaa Almost! I want to specify what columns to add, though.

Comment: `sapply(list[order(names(list))], function(x) sum(x[ ,1:2]))`

Comment: @Khashaa Thank you for this. You might be interested, but 'order' didn't work because, I think, the dataframes are nonatomic elements in the list. Still, it doesn't matter because the output provides the result with the matching dataframe. Thank you!

Comment: My solution differs from Khashaa's only in returning a vector as specified, but I developed and tested it independently.  When using data.tables the columns can be referenced by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one line method using an anonymous function:

```
a = 1
df1 <- data.frame(Col1=c(1,2,3,4,5),Col2=c(2,3,4,5,6), Col3=rep(a,5))
df3 <- data.frame(Col1=c(5,4,3,2,1),Col2=c(6,5,4,3,2), Col3=rep(a,5))
df2 <- data.frame(Col1=c(1,2,3,4,5),Col2=c(1,2,3,4,5), Col3=rep(a,5))
list <- list(df1 = df1, df3 =df3, df2 =df2)
r = unlist(lapply(list[order(names(list))], function(df) {sum(df[,1]) + sum(df[,2])}))
```

Comment: `sapply( list[sort(names(list))] , function(x) sum(colSums(x)) )  #df1 df2 df3 
 40  35  40 `

Comment: @BondedDust - yes sapply will do the unlist() to vectorize, which I guess is your point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using the sqldf package. Is this what you need?

```
library(sqldf)

df1 <- data.frame(Col1=c(1,2,3,4,5),Col2=c(2,3,4,5,6)) 
df3 <- data.frame(Col1=c(5,4,3,2,1),Col2=c(6,5,4,3,2))
df2 <- data.frame(Col1=c(1,2,3,4,5),Col2=c(1,2,3,4,5))
list <- list(df1, df3, df2)
list

df1 <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df1 ORDER BY Col1, Col2")
df2 <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df2 ORDER BY Col1, Col2")
df3 <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df3 ORDER BY Col1 DESC, Col2 DESC")
df1
df2
df3

df1 <- sqldf("SELECT SUM(Col1 +Col2) FROM df1")
df2 <- sqldf("SELECT SUM(Col1+Col2) FROM df2")
df3 <- sqldf("SELECT SUM(Col1+Col2) FROM df3")
df1
df2
df3

x <- vector()
x <- c(df1, df2, df3)
x
```

Which Gives the following result:

```
> x
$`SUM(Col1 +Col2)`
[1] 35

$`SUM(Col1+Col2)`
[1] 30

$`SUM(Col1+Col2)`
[1] 35
```